# Text file content loss on Boto S3 upload

Tags: python, amazon-s3, boto

I have been uploading text files to S3 and I came across this interesting error: the files aren't always uploaded, just the file name. So sometimes the entire file uploaded and sometimes I have a 0 byte file on S3. I have been using this tutorial:

http://stackabuse.com/example-upload-a-file-to-aws-s3/

Here is the code I have been using (minus keys and such):

```
#NOTE Section 8: Uploading to Amazon

AWS_ACCESS_KEY = ''
AWS_ACCESS_SECRET_KEY = ''

filea = open(date + '.txt', 'r+')

key = filea.name
bucket = ''





import os
import boto
from boto.s3.key import Key


##Beginning of function
def upload_to_s3(aws_access_key_id, aws_secret_access_key, filea, bucket, key, callback=None, md5=None, reduced_redundancy=False, content_type=None):
    """
    Uploads the given file to the AWS S3
    bucket and key specified.

    callback is a function of the form:

    def callback(complete, total)

    The callback should accept two integer parameters,
    the first representing the number of bytes that
    have been successfully transmitted to S3 and the
    second representing the size of the to be transmitted
    object.

    Returns boolean indicating success/failure of upload.
    """

    #   try:
     #      size = os.fstat(file.fileno()).st_size
    #   except:
            # Not all file objects implement fileno(),
            # so we fall back on this
     #      file.seek(0, os.SEEK_END)
      #     size = file.tell()

    conn = boto.connect_s3(aws_access_key_id, aws_secret_access_key)
    bucket = conn.get_bucket(bucket, validate=False)
    k = Key(bucket)
    k.key = key

    print k.key

    #if content_type:
     #  k.set_metadata('Content-Type', content_type)
    sent = k.set_contents_from_file(filea, cb=callback, md5=md5, reduced_redundancy=reduced_redundancy, rewind=True)

    print sent

        # Rewind for later use
    filea.seek(0)
    #print size

##End of function



upload_to_s3(AWS_ACCESS_KEY, AWS_ACCESS_SECRET_KEY, filea, bucket, key)
os.remove(date + '.txt')
```

Now some info about what I feed into this: earlier sections of the code write out a text file, there are multiple lines paragraphs, but still all one text file that was created with a+ permissions. The file is named using (date + '.txt') and is not closed in earlier sections of the code using .close() unless there is some subprocess that the python interpreter carries out that I am not aware of (.close() gave me a few issues so I just left it open, since the last line of my code here erases it).

I have tried looping the uploading process, but it seems like the file is just not read properly. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Boto does not rewind the file to 0 before it starts to upload.  If the file pointer you pass to `k.set_contents_from_file` is not at the beginning of the file then any data from the beginning to the file to its current position (as reported by fp.tell()) will not be sent.  This is by design and I would not consider this a bug in boto.

If you want to be sure the entire file is uploaded to S3, make sure the file pointer is at the beginning of the file before passing it to boto.  From the code you show above, you are doing a rewind after the upload but not before.